# How to make iPad rotations more fluid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I'll show you two methods: the first one "redefineLayout" calculate new positions of elements and the second one is the hook "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" after rotation.

```
- (void)redefineLayout
{
    int margin = 20;
    int buttonWidth = ((int)self.view.frame.size.width - margin * 4)/3;

    [self.buttonNewOrder setFrame:CGRectMake(margin, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
    [self.buttonStatistics setFrame:CGRectMake(margin * 2 + buttonWidth, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
    [self.buttonSincronize setFrame:CGRectMake(margin * 3 + buttonWidth * 2, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self redefineLayout];
}
```

My interface work but after rotations I see elements make a quick and unsightly movement. I'll like to make this movement more fluid. Any suggestion?

---

My solution:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self redesignLayout:duration];
}

- (void)redesignLayout:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        int margin = 20;
        int buttonWidth = (((int)self.view.frame.size.width) - margin * 4)/3;
        [self.buttonNewOrder setFrame:CGRectMake(margin, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
        [self.buttonStatistics setFrame:CGRectMake(margin * 2 + buttonWidth, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
        [self.buttonSincronize setFrame:CGRectMake(margin * 3 + buttonWidth * 2, 20, buttonWidth, 200)];
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initLayout];
    [self redesignLayout:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` call with this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self redefineLayout];
    }];
}
```